# How can I make an image view a bottom border for a layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-linearlayout

I have the following layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
    android:orientation="vertical"  
    android:clickable="true"    
    android:background="@drawable/mydrawable"   
    android:layout_width="match_parent"     
    android:layout_height=80dp"> 

    <TextView   
        android:id="@+id/my_text_view"        
        android:textSize="@dimen/label_text"    
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"      
        android:layout_height="match_parent"        
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/textPadding" 
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/textPadding"    
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/textPadding"       
        android:text="This is some text"/>

     <include layout="@layout/my_separator"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the layout my_separator.xml

```
<ImageView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"      
        android:layout_width="match_parent"         
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"         
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"       
        android:scaleType="fitXY"       
        android:src="#FF00FF"      />
```

Basically this layout has a text view and another layout that acts as a separator.

**Problem:**
I need to display the text in the middle of the layout and the separator to be at the very bottom. I.e. to act as the solid border of the parent linear layout.
So now it is like:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++   (linear layout)  
This is some text   
--------------------- (Separator)  


++++++++++++++++++++++++  (linear layout) - bottom
```

**But I want**

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++   (linear layout)  

This is some text   

------------------------ (Separator) - linear layout bottom
```

How can I do this?

**Note:** I need to keep the background that I already have for the layout

Comment: @SaschaKolberg:I have tried that inside the imageview. It did not work

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that in a `LinearLayout`. The problem is elements in a `LinearLayout` are in linear manner or in a line and you cant have spaces in a line. They could only be displayed vertically or horizontally linear.

You've to use `RelativeLayout` for this purpose. Something like this

```
 <RelativeLayout>
  <LinearLayout>
    <!-- All your other elements in here -->
  </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Include you'r seperator here -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yup, use a `RelativeLayout` with the separator set to `layout_alignParentBottom="true"`, and the `LinearLayout` set to `layout_above="@+id/the_id_you_give_the_separator"`

Comment: But can't I somehow make the image view the bottom border of the linear layout?

Answer (score 0):

Make the included layout have a layout gravity of bottom and the root linear layout should have a height of match parent

Comment: The `layout_gravity="bottom"` makes it go bellow the text but not to be the border

Comment: because root linear layout has height 80 dp , make it match parent

Comment: But I want the linear layout to have at least 80 dp height

Comment: then wrap the entire linear and textview in a match parent layout and as a sibling to the linear+text , include the seperator with a layoutgravity bottom

Comment: So it should be outside then?

Comment: yeah the include should be outside this linearlayout and the parent for this include layout and the linear layout existing should be recyclerview

Comment: I am sorry, what is `recyclerview`?

Comment: Sorry i meant a relativelayout

Answer (score 0):

As everybody have said you need to use RelativeLayout, but you need to wrap your layout using a LinearLayout, the only problem is, if you yave too much text and there is scrolling, the seprator will be static but you can try and check

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
    android:clickable="true"    
    android:background="@drawable/mydrawable"   
    android:layout_width="match_parent"     
    android:layout_height=80dp"> 

    <TextView   
       android:id="@+id/my_text_view"        
       android:textSize="@dimen/label_text"    
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"      
       android:layout_height="match_parent"        
       android:paddingTop="@dimen/textPadding" 
       android:paddingLeft="@dimen/textPadding"    
       android:paddingRight="@dimen/textPadding"       
       android:text="This is some text"/>

    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:gravity="bottom|center">

           <include layout="@layout/my_separator"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: But `android:gravity="bottom"` generally works for linear layouts as well

Comment: The answer is wrong. The `android:gravity="bottom"` determines the layout of the children. The second linear layout itself will not go to the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Are the `TextView` and the `include` the only children of the LinearLayout? If yes, you can use (I took out properties that are of no interest for this case):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="This is some text"/>

    <include
        layout="@layout/separator" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If you feel like the `TextView` could happen to require more space than what the parent can offer, you could set a `maxHeight` that would be (80 - heightOfTheSeparator - anyRelevantMargins/Paddings)